# MS SQL 2008, join 3 tables, filtering by columns in T1 and T2, find average of smallest values from T3 only

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've found similar, but not quite matching, scenarios on here, and have not had any luck getting this to work. Forgive me if this is a duplicate question, I definitely searched first! I've got three tables. The first, A, is a list of help desk tickets. The second, B, a list of time entries. The third, C, more details about the time entries in the second. For each item in A, there can be multiple items in B, but for each item in B there is only and exactly one entry for C.

**wh_task as A**

```
task_id   create_time              source_id   
========  ============             ==========  
1351000   2013-01-23 12:03:23.590  8          
1351001   2013-01-23 13:03:23.590  5
1351002   2013-01-23 15:03:23.590  8
```

**wh_time_item as B**

```
task_id   time_item_id   created_by_user_id
========  ============   =================
1351000   2456           1234567
1351000   2457           2345786
1351000   2458           1234567
```

**wh_time_subitem as C**

```
time_item_id  create_time              
========      ============             
2456          2013-01-23 12:43:23.590
2457          2013-01-25 13:13:23.590
2458          2013-02-12 16:03:23.590
```

High level objective - 
Determine the average FIRST response time for each ticket, by engineer, within a given date range.

Specifically - 
First, find all items in A that were created between @StartDate and @EndDate. Next, find all items in A where the source_id = 8 (these are the only tickets I care about). Then, I need to find which item in B is the "first" entry, i.e the date closest to the creation of the item in A. Table B doesn't have the creation date though - that's in C.
Once I've identified the item from B that was "first", I need to see if created_by_user_id matches @Engineer. Finally, I want the average of the date diff between a.create_time and c.create_time, in minutes for all matches. Something like AVERAGE(DATEDIFF(MI, a.create_time, c.createtime) as ResponseTime.

I've gone through a dozen iterations in the last two days, here's my broken query as it stands now. I know this query, even if it could run, wouldn't give me what I want - been fiddling with it to pull additional columns for troubleshooting purposes:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime
DECLARE @EndDate datetime
DECLARE @Engineer integer
SET @StartDate = '04/01/13'
SET @EndDate = '04/30/13 23:59:59'
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(S, (DateDiff(s, getdate(), getutcdate())), @StartDate)
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(S, (DateDiff(s, getdate(), getutcdate())), @EndDate)
SET @Engineer = 1234567

SELECT [task_number]
      ,a.[create_time]
      ,DateDiff(MI, a.create_time, c.create_time) as a_responsetime
      ,b.user_id
      ,c.[time_subitem_id]
      ,a.ticket_source_id
  FROM [databasename].[dbo].[wh_task] as a
LEFT JOIN [databasename].[dbo].[wh_time_item] AS b
  ON a.task_id = b.task_id
LEFT JOIN [[databasename].[dbo].[wh_time_subitem] AS c
  ON b.time_item_id = (SELECT c.time_item_id from [databasename].[dbo].[wh_time_subitem] WHERE c.create_time = (SELECT MIN(c.create_time) from [databasename].[dbo].[wh_time_subitem]))
WHERE 
  b.user_id = @Engineer
  AND a.ticket_source_id = 8
  AND c.create_time between @StartDate and @EndDate
  ORDER BY a.ticket_source_id
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide. I'm at best a SQL hobbyist, so don't worry about hurting my feelings. :-)

Comment: What's wrong with this (AVERAGE(DATEDIFF(MI, a.create_time, c.createtime))? have you any error by executing this?

Comment: The query above gives this error: An aggregate cannot appear in an ON clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference. I'm not certain that I'm on the right track in the first place though, so this error may just be muddying the waters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jazz, following up on the e-mail I sent you, using the following against your provided sample data, I get what I think is the correct data point you are looking for:

```
declare @StartDate datetime
declare @EndDate datetime
declare @Engineer int

SET @StartDate = '01/01/13'
SET @EndDate = '01/30/13 23:59:59'
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(S, (DateDiff(s, getdate(), getutcdate())), @StartDate)
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(S, (DateDiff(s, getdate(), getutcdate())), @EndDate)
SET @Engineer = 1234567

select AVG(first_response_time) from ( select A.*, DATEDIFF(minute, A.create_time, (
    select top 1 C.create_time
    from wh_time_item as B
        inner join wh_time_subitem as C on C.time_item_id = B.time_item_id
    order by C.create_time asc ) ) as first_response_time
from wh_task as A
    inner join wh_time_item as B on B.task_id = A.task_id
where A.source_id = 8
    and A.create_time between @StartDate and @EndDate
    and B.created_by_user_id = @Engineer
 ) as first_response_table
```

Note that the subquery against wh_time_item and wh_time_subitem assumes that create_time will always be on or after the wh_task create_time... which seems like a solid assumption.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much, that works great! Sorry for the delayed response, I only get to play with SQL in my in-between-projects time, so I wasn't able to get back to this until now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using this query above?

U know friend ...This error occurs when you use an `aggregate function` like `AVG()` directly in your `ON clause` statement . like This :

```
TableA join TableB on TableA.Code >= AVG(TableB.Code)
```

This query above has an error like yours

But Now you are using a subquery by having an `aggregate function` in ,It seems to be true. I meant this part of your query:

```
LEFT JOIN [[databasename].[dbo].[wh_time_subitem] AS c
ON b.time_item_id = (SELECT c.time_item_id from [databasename].[dbo].[wh_time_subitem] WHERE c.create_time = (SELECT MIN(c.create_time) from [databasename].[dbo].[wh_time_subitem]))
```

look this link : [Link](http://exacthelp.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/aggregate-cannot-appear-in-on-clause.html) may be helpfull